# karnaugh maps simplification

Tags: flipflop, counter, boolean-algebra

I'm in the process of making a JK arbitrary sequence counter and I'm now making the k maps to get a logic equation. I was just wondering if this is allowed (looping the bits around the middle bit) as I've not seen it in any textbooks or in videos, but I know that you're only meant to highlight 2,4,8 etc bits. Also, if this is allowed, is the logic equation below correct?

[image: k-map]

Comment: @Toor, you may want to post that as an answer. Simple, but good and helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is allowed. If it was not allowed you would have no way to deal with rows or columns of odd entries since your entries must always be grouped with even dimensions (except for single rows or columns).

The formula looks good to me.

Google K-maps if you're ever unsure since there are now a LOT of really clear examples compared to when I was in school which was not even that long ago. Either that or it was there but I was too stupid to realize I could look up material in places other than a textbook for help.